# Gparted error - Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: gparted, ubuntu-gnome

On Ubuntu Gnome 15.04,  Gparted will not launch from the icon. When launched from the terminal it gives the error 'Segmentation fault (core dumped)'.

It works fine on Ubuntu &  Ubuntu Mate 15.04.

Comment: Segmentation faults are a reason to report a bug (on launchpad.net) against this package (and as such are offtopic here).

Comment: If it didn't work on other flavors of Ubuntu, I would agree.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resolve "Segmentation fault (core dumped)"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/690565/how-to-resolve-segmentation-fault-core-dumped)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the library `libglibmm`, better `libglibmm-2.4-1c2a`

Check the output of this command:

```
apt-cache policy libglibmm-2.4-1c2a
```

Sample output:

```
% apt-cache policy libglibmm-2.4-1c2a
libglibmm-2.4-1c2a:
  Installed: 2.43.2-0ubuntu1~vivid1
  Candidate: 2.43.2-0ubuntu1~vivid1
  Version table:
 *** 2.43.2-0ubuntu1~vivid1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3-staging/ubuntu/ vivid/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.42.0-1 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/main amd64 Packages
```

Install an older version, eg: `2.42.0-1`

```
sudo apt-get install libglibmm-2.4-1c2a=2.42.0-1
```

and set the package on hold:

```
sudo apt-mark hold libglibmm-2.4-1c2a
```

reversible with

```
sudo apt-mark unhold libglibmm-2.4-1c2a
```

That worked in my case.

---

Output of `gdb`gpartedbin`

```
Starting program: /usr/sbin/gpartedbin

[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff6a6993a in Glib::wrap_register(unsigned long, Glib::ObjectBase* (*)(_GObject*)) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglibmm-2.4.so.1
(gdb) bt
#0 0x00007ffff6a6993a in Glib::wrap_register(unsigned long, Glib::ObjectBase* (*)(_GObject*)) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglibmm-2.4.so.1
#1 0x00007ffff6a5969e in Glib::wrap_init() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglibmm-2.4.so.1
#2 0x0000000000418ebf in ?? ()
#3 0x00007ffff49aea40 in __libc_start_main (main=0x418e90, argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe338, init=<optimized out>, fini=<optimized out>, rtld_fini=<optimized out>, stack_end=0x7fffffffe328) at libc-start.c:289
#4 0x0000000000419575 in ?? ()
```

Comment: Done. I will remember that for next time. Still new  here. Excellent job.

Comment: I get error:  "E: Version '2.42.0-1' for 'libglibmm-2.4-1c2a' was not found" on Ubuntu 14.04, what should I do?