# How to resolve "Segmentation fault (core dumped)"

Tags: 14.04

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.

After installing some applications I faced a segmentation fault (core dumped) error.

What does it mean ? How can I resolve this issue ?

**For example**:

After installing chrome-stable, when I launch it from terminal I experience this error.

Comment: Some binary program crashed, but this is very specific to the program that crashed, so you may need to tell us which program produced this, also you could try to update it.

Comment: See [what is a segmentation fault?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/138407/what-is-a-segmentation-fault)

Comment: As it is a closed source, you better raise a bug report to uncle GooGle!

Comment: Good SH :) I will ask uncle ;P

Comment: Try remove it's preferences & cache, `sudo rm -rf ~/.config/google-chrome ~/.cache/google-chrome` . Then run it is incognito mode `google-chrome --incognito`

Comment: @Ravan, are still facing this problem.  install gdb then run `gdb /opt/google/chrome/chrome`, on gdb enter this command `run`  to start chrome inside debugger. add output to your question. Then still in gdb enter `backtrack` command. and post its output too. I just want confirm if it is the same problem I just seen and fix by downgrading libnss3. `sudo apt-get install libnss3=2:3.15.4-1ubuntu7 libnss3-nssdb=2:3.15.4-1ubuntu7 `

Comment: @Sneetsher thanks =) I remember, I have solved the error. Will you please write answer in general way to solve that particular error. I mean irrespective of  app which created that error, can you write general solution/way to proceed?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### What does it mean?

See [AU: What is a segmentation fault?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138407/what-is-a-segmentation-fault) post and also this post which have some examples how reproduce it, [SO: What is segmentation fault?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2346806/724406).

The simplest description I can come with (may be not the perfect):

> The program tried to access a memory area out side its own section. Operating system blocks it.

**Some cases:** Reading value with uninitialized pointer, Going out of range in an array, Function call (when backward compatibility not maintained), ...

However, it is not always easy find the cause with large programs or those which relay on other project lib's. And most of the cases end up with a *bug report*, either for target program or one of its dependencies (either upstream project or downstream distribution package).

### How can I resolve this issue?

- #### Fire a bug report

  If you didn't make any custom configuration/setup and you all updates installed. *fire a bug report*, see [How do I report a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug)

  If open source supported by Ubuntu use `ubuntu-bug` (`apport-bug`). For 3rd party closed source, check their help pages how to report bugs and collect related data.
- #### Take initiative to debug

  If you you have even a little programming background, it is recommended that you try your best to resolve it yourself. There many bug reports out there inactive for years. At least, you may be able to collect enough debug data that help resolve the issue when reporting it.

  That's means that you are breaking the user abstraction level and opening the black box! (FLOSS actually has transparent box).

### Some Useful Tools for Debugging

Some ... I mean there are many other useful tools out there that you gonna find when you dig in more.

1. #### `apport-bug` logs / core dump / backtrace

   If you don't have an error message before segmentation fault. Run it with `--save` option and look for back-trace log:

   ```
   apport-bug program-cmd --save bug-report_output.txt
   ```
2. #### `gdb` backtrace / debuging source code

   If it didn't work, use `gdb`:

   ```
   $ gdb program-cmd
   (gdb) run
   (gdb) backtrace
   ```

   If you get any error message, check the web, launchpad and in upstream project bug tracker if there any similar cases.

   For some advanced users or who are following a c/c++ learning path, they could download the corresponding `-dbg` symbols packages. Then you can use `gdb` to trace program flow through the source and get the exact function/instruction that raise the runtime error.

   For Ubuntu(Debian) based distributions, source code of a package can be downloaded using:

   ```
   apt-get source <package-name>
   ```
3. #### `strace` system call tracing

   Another tool that may help is `strace`, I like it. It's really a powerful tool.

   It presents itself:

   > In the simplest case **`strace`** runs the specified command until it exits.  It intercepts and records the system calls which are  called  by  a
   >              process  and  the signals which are received by a process.  The name of each system call, its arguments and its return value are printed on
   >              standard error or to the file specified with the -o option.
   >
   > **`strace`** is a useful diagnostic, instructional, and debugging tool.  System administrators, diagnosticians and trouble-shooters will find  it
   >              invaluable  for  solving  problems  with  programs for which the source is not readily available since they do not need to be recompiled in
   >              order to trace them.  Students, hackers and the overly-curious will find that a great deal can be learned about a  system  and  its  system
   >              calls  by  tracing  even  ordinary  programs.   And programmers will find that since system calls and signals are events that happen at the
   >              user/kernel interface, a close examination of this boundary is very useful for bug isolation, sanity checking  and  attempting  to capture
   >              race conditions.

   <sup>**Source:** [`man strace`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/strace.1.html)</sup>
4. #### `ltrace` dynamic library call tracing

   > `ltrace` is a program that simply runs the  specified  command  until 
   >   it
   >          exits.   It  intercepts and records the dynamic library calls which are
   >          called by the executed process and the signals which  are  received  by
   >          that  process.   It  can also intercept and print the system calls exe‐
   >          cuted by the program.
   >
   > Its use is very similar to `strace`(1).

   <sup>**Source:** [`man ltrace`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/ltrace.1.html)</sup>

Comment: Thanks. `gdb -ex=run --args my_program arg1 arg2` helped me find the problem.