# xdotool - segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: xdotool

I installed `xdotool` in Ubuntu. But it says `segmentation fault (core dumped)` when I inputted command `xdotool getmouselocation`. How to solve it?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using? Are you actually running X, or another system like Wayland or Mir?

Comment: my ubuntu version is ubuntu 16.04.What is the X?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System

Comment: How to install X_Window_System in ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: I had install X Window System use the command as follows:
# apt-get install xserver-xorg 
# apt-get install x-window-system-core 
# dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg 
# apt-get install gnome-core 
# apt-get install gdm xscreensaver 
# apt-get install ttf-arphic*
# startx
.And input command "export DISPLAY=:0".Than xdotool can work now.

Comment: But it has another question.Please look at the link "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=25OTHjiVHZg".The value is x:512 y:384 of the screen coordinates,But the coordinates value is x:512 y:384 still when i change the location of mouse pointer in screen.Why the coordinates value do not change?I want get the screen coordinates current value of mouse pointer.

Comment: I'm happy you got xdotool working at least! Please post that as an answer. (You can answer your own question.) As for the coordinates issue, please [ask a new question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask).

Comment: please look at the new question link "https://askubuntu.com/questions/1035940/i-use-xdotool-can-not-get-the-screen-coordinates-value-of-current-mouse-pointer".

Answer (score 0):

You might be using not real display. To correct this, do:

```
export DISPLAY=:0  
xdotool getmouselocation
```

If it did not work, this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/690565/how-to-resolve-segmentation-fault-core-dumped) might be useful.

Comment: I had correct this:
export DISPLAY=:0  
xdotool getmouselocation.
But it says "Error:Can't open display:(null) Failed creating new xdo instance" now.

Comment: try to use `export DISPLAY=:1`, then try again

Comment: I had try to use "export DISPLAY=:1",But it says "segmentation fault (core dumped)" now.

Comment: I had install X Window System use the command as follows:
# apt-get install xserver-xorg 
# apt-get install x-window-system-core 
# dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg 
# apt-get install gnome-core 
# apt-get install gdm xscreensaver 
# apt-get install ttf-arphic*
# startx
And input command "export DISPLAY=:0".Than xdotool can work now.

Comment: But it has another question.Please look at the link "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=25OTHjiVHZg".The value is x:512 y:384 of the screen coordinates,But the coordinates value is x:512 y:384 still when i change the location of mouse pointer in screen.Why the coordinates value do not change?I want get the screen coordinates current value of mouse pointer.

Answer (score 0):

I had to install X Window System using the commands as follows:

```
# apt-get install xserver-xorg 
# apt-get install x-window-system-core 
# dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg 
# apt-get install gnome-core 
# apt-get install gdm xscreensaver 
# apt-get install ttf-arphic*
# startx
```

And input command `export DISPLAY=:0`. `xdotool` works now.

Comment: Please look at the new question link https://askubuntu.com/questions/1035940/i-use-xdotool-can-not-get-the-screen-coordinates-value-of-current-mouse-pointer%22