# Calibre crashes with "Segmentation fault" (core dumped)

Tags: crash, calibre

I am using Ubuntu 16.04. LTS and I have calibre installed. Unfortunately, it doesn't launch anymore and crashes on startup without any error message. When I launch calibre from terminal (to get some more info), all I get as answer after the crash is:

Segmentation fault (core dumped)

What to do?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Cheers
ijon

Comment: You can find some more information [using these procedures](https://askubuntu.com/a/704046/283721)

Answer (score 1):

can be closed. updating calibre and stopping to rely on original sources did the trick. now I am running a binary from calibre itself.

just go here, download the library and stop hoping that the version within the ppa-system will work again: https://calibre-ebook.com/download_linux

Comment: Oddly, I've never used the version from the Ubuntu libraries - I have found that Calibre is updated pretty often by the developer.