# Packet Tracer 7.2 on Ubuntu 19.04 no version information available

Tags: apt, package-management, 19.04

I am trying to install Packet Tracer on Ubuntu 19.04, but it gives me the error below when I try to launch it:

```
./PacketTracer7: ./libcrypto.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by ./PacketTracer7)
```

But when I try to install `libssl1.0.0` I get the following error:

```
**Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libssl1.0.0 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source**

**E: Package 'libssl1.0.0' has no installation candidate**
```

I also collected a debug for this:

```
Reading symbols from PacketTracer7...
(No debugging symbols found in PacketTracer7)
(gdb) run
Starting program: /opt/pt/bin/PacketTracer7 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
[New Thread 0x7fffeda96700 (LWP 2775)]
[New Thread 0x7fffece7a700 (LWP 2776)]
[New Thread 0x7fffa7ffd700 (LWP 2778)]

Thread 1 "PacketTracer7" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000000034602dc in CDeviceTypesBox::CDeviceTypesBox(QVector<SDeviceTypes_t*>, QWidget*, char const*, QFlags<Qt::WindowType>) ()
(gdb) where
#0  0x00000000034602dc in CDeviceTypesBox::CDeviceTypesBox(QVector<SDeviceTypes_t*>, QWidget*, char const*, QFlags<Qt::WindowType>) ()
#1  0x0000000003473201 in CNetworkComponentBox::CNetworkComponentBox(QWidget*, char const*, QFlags<Qt::WindowType>) ()
#2  0x0000000002e9ba0a in Ui_CAppWindowBase::setupUi(QMainWindow*) ()
#3  0x0000000002e96b26 in CAppWindow::CAppWindow(QWidget*, char const*, QFlags<Qt::WindowType>) ()
#4  0x000000000341c801 in oldMain(int, char**) ()
#5  0x00007ffff406cb6b in __libc_start_main (main=0x541620 <main>, argc=1, 
    argv=0x7fffffffdf48, init=<optimized out>, fini=<optimized out>, 
    rtld_fini=<optimized out>, stack_end=0x7fffffffdf38)
    at ../csu/libc-start.c:308
#6  0x000000000054ad79 in _start ()
```

Thanks in advance for helping me. And again, excuse my lack of technical knowledge to explain this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can try downloading one from [18.10 repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/cosmic/amd64/libssl1.0.0/download), since it's yet to be available on 19.04.

```
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl1.0/libssl1.0.0_1.0.2n-1ubuntu6.2_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libssl1.0.0_1.0.2n-1ubuntu6.2_amd64.deb
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jim (and for the url to the package), I ran the commands and it seems they were successful:

(Reading database ... 159000 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack libssl1.0.0_1.0.2n-1ubuntu6.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libssl1.0.0:amd64 (1.0.2n-1ubuntu6.2) over (1.0.2n-1ubuntu6.2) ...
Setting up libssl1.0.0:amd64 (1.0.2n-1ubuntu6.2) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.29-0ubuntu2) ...

But I keep getting the same error when I try to execute Packet Tracer.

Comment: @tierianoob Try this `sudo cp -i /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 /opt/pt/bin/ ` press y to confirm overwrite. [Solution from YT](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HKozuo2FmMA)

Comment: I ran it, and not it doesn't complain about the library, I only get this error:

Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: @tierianoob Do you have `/opt/pt/bin` dir ? Can you by any chance copy it manually ?

Comment: I did it manually but got the same error as I tried to run it. However, when I tried to ran it as root, it took longer and eventually returned the same message but didn't mention any core dump. Do you know where could I find this coredump?

Comment: I think coredump is unrelated to the problem, see link for details https://askubuntu.com/questions/690565/how-to-resolve-segmentation-fault-core-dumped

Comment: Thanks for the help, unfortunately it seems that I won't be running that app for the a while

Answer (score 0):

I ran into some trouble getting PT to run on Ubuntu 19.04 and after a bit of research it looks like not only is the libpng12 package required but it needs further customization due to /lib being a symlink to /usr/lib now. While I appreciate the folks dropping links to custom .deb packages I wanted to roll my own

Assumes PacketTracer 7.2.2 has already been installed to /opt/pt

```bsh
#create dir to hold libpng12
sudo mkdir /opt/pt/libpng
cd /opt/pt/libpng

#obtain official package
sudo wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libp/libpng/libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb .

#extract package
sudo dpkg-deb -x libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb ./libpng12

#Original package structure
libpng12/
├── lib
│   └── x86_64-linux-gnu
│       ├── libpng12.so.0 -> libpng12.so.0.54.0
│       └── libpng12.so.0.54.0
└── usr
    ├── lib
    │   └── x86_64-linux-gnu
    │       └── libpng12.so.0 -> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0
    └── share
        └── doc
            └── libpng12-0
                ├── ANNOUNCE
                ├── changelog.Debian.gz
                ├── copyright
                ├── KNOWNBUG
                ├── libpng-1.2.54.txt.gz
                ├── README.Debian
                ├── README.gz
                └── TODO

#export package detail 
sudo dpkg-deb -e libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb ./libpng12/DEBIAN

#remove symlink from /usr/lib
sudo rm ./libpng12/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0

#move all contents from /lib to /usr/lib 
sudo mv ./libpng12/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/* ./libpng12/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/

#build package
sudo dpkg-deb -b ./libpng12 libpng12-0_1.2.54_amd64_custom.deb

#install custom package
sudo apt install ./libpng12-0_1.2.54_amd64_custom.deb
```