# Ruby on Rails on Ubuntu 19.0.4 crashing

Tags: libraries, ruby, openssl, ruby-on-rails

How to add following dependencies to start my rails server:
While starting the server using following command `bin/start thin` getting following error message:

> /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': libssl.so.1.0.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so (LoadError)

After upgrading Ubuntu this issues happened, as I have cleaned some files along with installation. Not sure how to solve this.

#### Update

If I try to start the server using command: `bin/start`

Getting different error message:

> /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/digest.rb:16:in `const_missing': library not found for class Digest::SHA1 -- digest/sha1 (LoadError)

Comment: Try installing openssl as suggested in my other answer --> https://askubuntu.com/a/1142013/253251

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have a broken install? In this case, reinstalling the package with `apt` should solve the problem. Or maybe you could run `sudo apt install -f` to fix packages? It looks like of the shared library (or modules) are missing.

Comment: `sudo apt install -f` this didn't fixed the problem

Comment: Then yes, maybe you should install OpenSSL Jim mentioned.