# Lubuntu 18.10 gparted gui error

Tags: lubuntu, gparted

I can't open gparted.
When I open it by terminal: sudo gparted;
It gives me this:

```
Unit tmp.mount does not exist, proceeding anyway.
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I tried to follow this procedure:
[Gparted error - Segmentation fault (core dumped)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/617057/gparted-error-segmentation-fault-core-dumped)

But it didn't work, I suppose this is a solution ment for old architecture. The result on my terminal is this:

```
E: Version ‘2.42.0-1’ for ‘libglibmm-2.4-1c2a’ was not found
```

I remember I used gparted during setup for my system when I installed cosmic. weird. It must be caused by a modification i did. Some sites call it a 'bug'. Some help is required.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't have any useful information on your problem sorry (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libglibmm) but Lubuntu 18.10 relies on Qt, so I'd suggest trying KDE Partition Manager (`partitionmanager`) which comes pre-installed with Lubuntu 18.10  (it uses Qt libs used by Lubuntu 18.10, not GTK+ libs of `gparted`)

Comment: @guiverc, I don't see `partitionmanager` on my Lubuntu 18.10. Please check your system with `apt list --installed | grep -i part`. `partionmanager` *is* installed initially but it is subsequently removed by the installtion process via a purge operation. Check your `/var/log/apt/history.log*` files.

Comment: `partitionmanager` is preferably accessed from a Live USB after making sure relevant partitions are not mounted.

Comment: Sorry leeuwtje, and you are correct @DKBose.  It existed on my 19.04 system (and I don't recall adding it) so I assumed it'd be on a 18.10; booted a 18.10 & nope.

Comment: On my Lubuntu 18.10, which is relatively clean, a simulation shows that only one additional package will be installed if I install `partitionmanager`. The additional package is  `libkpmcore7 (3.3.0-3 Ubuntu:18.10/cosmic [amd64])`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in [a comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1097291/lubuntu-18-10-gparted-gui-error#comment1807568_1097291) by @guiverc, it would perhaps be more convenient to use *partitionmanager* on *qt*-based systems.

While *partitionmanager* is initially installed as part of Lubuntu 18.10, an automatic purge removes it and so a full install of Lubuntu 18.10 lacks *partitionmanager*:

```
Start-Date: 2018-11-21  18:15:54
Commandline: apt-get --purge -q -y remove ^live-* calamares-settings-lubuntu calamares hunspell-en-us zram-config partitionmanager cifs-utils
Purge: hunspell-en-us:amd64 (1:2018.04.16-1), calamares-settings-lubuntu:amd64 (27), casper:amd64 (1.399), lupin-casper:amd64 (0.57build1), calamares:amd64 (3.2.2-0ubuntu1), cifs-utils:amd64 (2:6.8-2), calamares-settings-ubuntu-common:amd64 (27), partitionmanager:amd64 (3.3.1-2), zram-config:amd64 (0.5)
End-Date: 2018-11-21  18:16:23

Start-Date: 2018-11-21  18:16:26
Commandline: apt-get --purge -q -y autoremove
Purge: libkpmcore7:amd64 (3.3.0-3), localechooser-data:amd64 (2.71ubuntu3), user-setup:amd64 (1.63ubuntu5)
End-Date: 2018-11-21  18:16:31
```

Anyway, the user can simply re-install *partitionmanager* with `sudo apt install partitionmanager` after which it will appear in the menu as *KDE Partition Manager*.

[image: KDE Partition Manager]

Comment: Thank everyone! 
I just installed partition manager, and I must say it is a very good solution. I didn't explore all functions in it yet, but it seems very similar to gparted in all aspects. I think the user interface is prettier:) Technical it is a much better solution  using this than messing with old lib package to get them installed in attempts to force gparted getting installed. I have 2 things now. 1. a good partition manager 2. A healthy system. A super help.